# Disabling autocommit in mysql hungs out the query

Tags: mysql

I have a big (~5gb) sql dump, which I need to import, but after 2-4 stack queries (~1700 queries that take 0.5 - 1.5 sec) comes a stack query which exection takes for about a minute.

When I disable autocommit (SET autocommit = 0;), then all the queries go ok, but on some point mysql just hungs out and do nothing. 
That issue comes out only when I set autocommit to zero.

What can be the problem and how can I solve it?

Comment: If you issue a `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` while importing, do you see a query at the time you believe MySQL hangs?

Comment: ALTER TABLE `table_name` ENABLE KEYS. It does work although with smaller dump (same schema)

Comment: I know that `ALTER TABLE` at least for MyISAM tables can take ages. One table, 100 million records, and an `ALTER TABLE ORDER BY` took about 11 hours.

Comment: @Shi, so what can I do? I cannot delete it manually, the file is very huge